# Expansion of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left(\frac{x^{n+\frac{1}{2}} - x^{-n-\frac{1}{2}}}{x^{\frac{1}{2}} - x^{-\frac{1}{2}}} \right) $

Tags: calculus, power-series

For $x\neq 0$, and probably with $|x|<1$, I want to show the following equation

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n  \left(\frac{x^{n+\frac{1}{2}} - x^{-n-\frac{1}{2}}}{x^{\frac{1}{2}} - x^{-\frac{1}{2}}} \right)  = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(x^n+x^{n-1} + \cdots + x^{-n}) \tag{1} $$

Is this valid expression, if so how can prove this?

---

My simple trial is 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n  \left(\frac{x^{n+\frac{1}{2}} - x^{-n-\frac{1}{2}}}{x^{\frac{1}{2}} - x^{-\frac{1}{2}}} \right) 
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{-n} - x^{n+1}}{1-x} 
\end{align}
I tried to expand this using geometric series, but having trouble obtain R.H.S of equation (1).

Comment: Note that the $n=0$ term of your LHS is just $1$. So all you really need to do is show that the term in parentheses on your LHS is the same as the term in parentheses on your RHS. (Try multiplying out $(x^{1/2}-x^{-1/2})(x^n+x^{n-1}+\cdots +x^{-n})$ by hand.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we have
$$\begin{align}
x^n+x^{n-1}+\dots+x^{-n}
&=x^{-n}(1+x+\dots+x^{2n})\\
&=x^{-n}\cdot\frac{1-x^{2n+1}}{1-x}\\
&=\frac{x^{-n}-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\\
&=\frac{x^{n+1}-x^{-n}}{x-1}\\
&=\frac{x^{n+1/2}-x^{-n-1/2}}{x^{1/2}-x^{-1/2}}\\
\end{align}$$